# widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset error in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I am trying to create a chart with invient charts in vaadin. I added relevant jars and create another application servlet which points to jquery highchart and modules files and modified the web.xml file. When I add my pie chart code; I get the following from the browser ;

`Widgetset does not contain implementation for com.invient.vaadin.charts.InvientCharts.
 Check its @ClientWidget mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions. Unrendered UIDL:
-Unrendered UIDL
-com.invient.vaadin.charts.InvientCharts(NO CLIENT IMPLEMENTATION FOUND) id=PID5 height=400px width=100.0% isRetrieveSVG=false isPrint=false reloadChartSeries=false
-options
-title text=Distribution of positive negative tweets
-subtitle
-credit
-position
-legend
-tooltip
-chart type=pie zoomType= clientZoom=true
-seriesOptionsPerSeriesType
-pie allowPointSelect=true cursor=pointer showInLegend=true
-dataLabel enabled=false
-state
-xAxes
-yAxes
-labels
-chartData
-series name=Status xAxis=0 yAxis=0
-pie
-points
-point name=Positive x=0 y=10 isShift=false
-point name=Negative x=1 y=20 isShift=false
-events
-chartEvents
-seriesEvents
-series
-pointEvents
-line
-pointEvents
-spline
-pointEvents
-scatter
-pointEvents
-area
-pointEvents
-areaspline
-pointEvents
-bar
-pointEvents
-column
-pointEvents
-pie
-pointEvents
-chartDataUpdates
-seriesDataUpdate seriesName=Status operation=Add isReloadPoints=false
-pointsAdded
-pointsRemoved`

and when I press compile vaadin widgets button, I get;

`select a widgetset file(..widgetset.gwt.xml) or a vaadin project to compile.`

What seems to be a problem here? In my other projects this widgetset.gwt.xml is created by eclipse.

Since I am a vaadin-invient charts newbie I don't what to put here such as logs etc., so if you let me know I will provide these information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this problem, I have added a gwt.xml file in to my project manually and copied my other project's gwt.xml content into my newly created gwt.xml and then added reference to newly created gwt.xml in the project's web.xml file.

Comment: can you elaborate why you did that and how did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify you answer:

> and when I press compile vaadin widgets button, I get:
>
> select a widgetset file(..widgetset.gwt.xml) or a vaadin project to compile.

I think this is because you had multiple .gtw.xml file in your application and the vaadin plugin couldn't know which was your default wigetset.
You need to manually select the default widgetset (that is in .widgetset package) and press the button again.

If in your application you don't have any other .gwt.xml file then, the procedure to add a new plugin to the application is well described here https://vaadin.com/directory/help/using-vaadin-add-ons